# NodeJS: Using readable event along with drain event

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream, node.js-stream

I am trying to read a large file (~800 MB) using node's readable stream.
I have subscribed to 'readable' event, on getting data i am writing to response and then wait for drain event to read data again. But drain event is getting triggered only 3-4 times. Please let me know if there is anything wrong.

```
// Assume res to be any writable stream.

var readStream = fs.createReadStream('C:/movie.mp4');

readStream
    .on('error', function (err) {
    })
    .on('readable', function () {
        console.log('READABLE event fired');
        writeStreamData(readStream, res);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log('END event fired');
        res.end();
    });

function writeStreamData(readStream, res) {
    var chunk, isFlushed;
    console.log('in writeStreamData');
    if (null !== (chunk = readStream.read(1024 * 1000))) {
        console.log('writing data');
        isFlushed = res.write(chunk);
        if (!isFlushed) {
            console.log('waiting for drain event');
            res.once('drain', function () {
                console.log('*** DRAIN event triggered');
                writeStreamData(readStream, res);
            });
        } else {
            writeStreamData(readStream, res);
        }
    }
}
```